# Achieving t random variables with each different df and ncp in R?

Tags: r, function, random

I'm trying to generate 5 random ***t variates*** using `rt()`, with each of the 5 having a particular `df` (respectively, from 1 to 5) and a particular `ncp` (respectively, `seq(0, 1, l = 5)`). So, 5 random t-variables each having a different `df` and a different `ncp`.

To achieve the above, ***I tried the below*** with no success. What could be the efficient R code to achieve what I described above?

```
vec.rt = Vectorize(function(n, df, ncp) rt(n, df, ncp), c("n", "df", "ncp"))

vec.rt(n = 5, df = 1:5, ncp = seq(0, 1, l = 5))
```

Or

```
mapply(FUN = rt, n = 5 , df = 1:5, ncp = seq(0, 1, l = 5))
```

**Notice** for:

```
rt(n = 5, df = 1:5, ncp = seq(0, 1, l = 5))
```

R gives the following warning:

`Warning message:
In if (is.na(ncp)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rephrasing your question helps to find an answer: you want sample of length 1 (`n = 1`) from 5 random variables each having different parameters.

```
mapply(FUN = rt, n = 1 , df = 1:5, ncp = seq(0, 1, l = 5))
```